# How to add another icon on mobile resolution in HTML Canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas, responsive

I have a template from a themeforest called Canvas (`version 5.1`) and now I am exploring, and I want to add languages instead of these icons

[image: normal size window],

I wanted just to replace search icon with "EN" and "ES" but on mobile resolution I only see one icon like this:

[image: mobile sized window]

**How can I manage to be able to preview both icons, both languages?**

Here is the access to my test project:

[Test repo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qTXfGV8XyQZJPnIDCQYHUSHpNW2v4FD0)
I added double icon search
Please click on index.html

Update:
By the courteousy of Mr. Gracias here is the not so good preview of my header if I add `style="left:10px"`

[image: example]

I want to be search icons one beside other also as in on big screen.

Answer (score 0):

on mobile devices both icons are placed on top of each other add below code to any of 1 of the icon. thanks

1. add class `icon` to 1 of the icon.
2. add below code in the css file.

   @media (min-width: 334px)
   { #top-search a i.icon{left:-45px}

   }

   @media (min-width: 992px){
   . #top-search a i.icon{left:-45px}
   }

Comment: you were right, that two elements overlapping each other, but if I put left:10px, I do not get what I want. Please review your comment, so that I can you give correct answer. Also please see my updated post with commenting your approach thanks

Comment: first of all you are expecting me to go through the whole code and check where the issue and expecting me to give for proper pixel alignment. StackOverflow doesn't work like that. you need to put minimal code so it is easy for us to work on it. anyway I have updated my answer please check. if still you have problem than create a code snippet of your code. i cannot again n again check your full code. thanks

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but still not works as expected.

Comment: send screenshot

Comment: i have updated my answer and it worked for me. thanks